# Original Application Version is missing in App Store receipt

Tags: ios, app-store, storekit, receipt

My iOS app grandfathers users, who purchased the app before September 2018, by checking the App Store receipt's `original_application_version` field. For around the last two weeks, this value is no longer present for some of my App Store users. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on my own devices yet, but have collected the following observations based on numerous email conversations:

- The receipt itself is present. Otherwise, my app would show a dialog box, which none of my users have seen so far.
- I know that the `original_application_version` is missing because my app reads and attaches this value to generated support emails.
- Users have tried to restore their purchases without any effect. The value is still missing.
- Other fields of the receipt seem to be unaffected. For example, my app can read and restore in-app purchases without any problems.
- This issue affects users on iOS 12 and iOS 13. My app requires iOS 11.4 or later.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue or how to debug it? The receipt parsing worked fine until about two weeks ago and I haven't made any changes to this part of my codebase in months.

Thank you!

Comment: I have see the same issue for some users of my app. Apple Developer Program Support has informed me that Apple is aware of the issue and they're working on it. They recommended to file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm now using `original_purchase_date` as a fallback. This field seems to be unaffected from the issue so far.